# Get foreground color of UITextField.placeHolder property?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsattributedstring, swift3

I'm trying to get the foreground color of a UITextField.placeHolder object. I have to use one of the following members of the [NSAttributeString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/):

```
attributesAtIndex(_:effectiveRange:)
attributesAtIndex(_:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:)
attribute(_:atIndex:effectiveRange:)
attribute(_:atIndex:longestEffectiveRange:inRange:)
```

There are a million examples on how to set attributes of an NSAttributeString,

```
uiTextFieldObject.attributedPlaceholder = 
   NSAttributedString(string:"placeholder text", attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
```

But I cannot find a simple example that retrieves a NSAttributeString attribute value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - Place add validations

## Swift

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Temp String",
                                              attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])

    attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                        inRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)){(attribute, range, other) in

        if let color = attribute as? UIColor {
            print("color \(color)")
        }
    }
```

## Objective-C

```
NSAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                   initWithString:@"Temp String"
                                   attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];

[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
                options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    if (value) {
        UIColor *color = (UIColor *)value;
        NSLog(@"Color : %@", color);
    }
}];
```

Comment: D-Griffin, thank you. I'm a seasoned programmer, but new to Swift and iOS; Objective-C is like an alien language to me. I'll give it a go!